# Need to know login rights on server without having viewing rights

Tags: sql

I am working on recommendations of Microsoft using RAP tool.

we have got 2 exceptions
The SQL Server Agent service is not using a recommended account
The SQL Server Full-text service is not using a recommended account

problem is login which is used for running SQL server agent which has some rights
my login doesn't have rights to view that login

when I am running query

```
select * from sys.logins
```

I can only see logins which I have rights too how to see all logins with their access data

Please help me.

Comment: Log in as the administrator?

Comment: i cant , i cant have that rights. any other way to find out

Comment: Ask the administrator for help?

Answer (score 1):

You can't...and a moment thinking about it should tell you why.

Any access model permits you to view **exactly** what you are allowed to view. You need to ask someone with higher level permissions for the information or access you require.